# How to understand JavaScript's "delete h[key]" and Python's "del h[key]"?

Tags: dictionary

There is one thing I can't really understand in JavaScript or Python, and that's the `delete` or `del` syntax.

In JavaScript:

```
obj = {ha: 123, hi: 3.14}
delete obj.ha               # now obj is {hi: 3.14}
```

In Python:

```
d1 = {"ha" : 123, "hi" : 3.14}
del d1["ha"]                # now d1 is {'hi': 3.14}
```

But, what does `delete obj.ha` or `del d1["ha"]` mean?

In JavaScript, `delete obj.ha` can mean `delete 123`, because `obj.ha` evaluates to `123`.

Likewise, in Python, `del d1["ha"]` can mean `del 123` because `d1["ha"]` evaluates to `123`.

So it doesn't make sense to `delete 123` in either case.

So are we saying, well, most of the time, the rules of evaluating something and then apply it to the `delete` or `del` operator work, but sometimes, they just "magically" work the other way?

For example, I think Smalltalk or Ruby's way make a whole lot more sense, which is `h.delete("ha")`, which is to say, pass the message to the `h` object, which is a dictionary or hash, that for the key `ha`, please remove it.  This is coherent with everything else. Then we don't have the weird thing as `delete obj.ha` -- oh it is not the same as `delete 123`.

(Python's `h.pop(key)` has the same effect of `del h[key]`, it seems, by the way, but having the syntax `del h[key]` still seems weird).

Comment: For Javascript, the only reason I can come up with is that it's an operator because that looks familiar to OOP veterans from C++/Java/etc, even though what the operator does in JS has nothing to do with what it does in those languages. The `new` operator is in a very similar but far more confusing position (at least `delete`'s behavior is extremely simple).

Comment: simple but confusing

Comment: @太極者無極而生: Not really confusing if you think of it as the inverse of assignment. You don't call a method to *create* a field either, you use an operator (`=`).

Comment: Note: Ruby has the same thing with the `defined?` operator, for example, and both Ruby and Smalltalk have the same thing with assignment, as pointed out by @JacquesB both in this [comment](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/311956/how-to-understand-javascripts-delete-hkey-and-pythons-del-hkey#comment658482_311956) and in his [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/311958/1352). There *are* languages where there is no assignment, and this is done with method calls, but they are not very mainstream. Ioke and Seph, for example.

Answer (score 3):

What we have after `delete` is an *lvalue*, which means the expression is not evaluated to the value in the field, but rater to an reference to the field itself.

The same happens in a more well-known construct:

```
obj.ha = 456
```

If the expression on the left hand were evaluated to the value first, it would be equivalent to this:

```
123 = 456
```

Which does not make any sense, because you cannot assign to an integer.

It is specified in the language grammar that expressions in certain contexts are not evaluated to a value but rater to a reference to a variable or field. The example are the left side of an assignment, and after the `delete` keyword.

Therefore it is pretty restricted what you can put in an lvalue position: It has to be a variable or a field. Any other expressions, like say a function call, is disallowed.

`del`/`delete` is basically the inverse of assignment, which creates a field/variable if it doesn't exist already. So I would argue it is not really weird or confusing but rather pretty logical. After all, you don't have to call `obj.createField("ha")` to create a field either, but use an operator (`=`).

Comment: does `lvalue` have the name due to the fact that it appears at the left?  So `delete d.ha` is having a lvalue at the right... and so I suppose you have to know when is an lvalue appearing at the right... or left, besides the assignment statement

Comment: I believe it means *location value*, because you return the location of a field or variable rather than the value it contains.

Comment: I think if we are to think of `obj.ha` as a reference, and `1 + obj.ha` means to "dereference" it and give you `123`, while `obj.ha = 345` means to make the reference point to `345`.  And `delete obj.ha`... to make the reference `ha` disappear from `obj`.  I suppose most of the time, it is affecting the reference `ha` -- or I tend to think about it related to `ha`, but in the case of `delete` it is affecting the `obj`... to remove something from `obj`

Comment: If we think about it in low-level C code, we may think of it as, `p` being a pointer, and high level language's `1 + obj.p` means `1 + *(obj.p)` in C -- to dereference the pointer and take the value.  If it is "location", then it means, in high level language `obj.p = 123`, the same as in C's `obj.p = &(123)` meaning the `p` is set to point to the address of the address of the object `123`, assuming `123` is an Integer object... so both cases, they are affecting `p`. Now `delete obj.p` doesn't affect `p`.  It affects `obj`

Comment: Think about it in terms of method calls, which C doesn't have, so it's not a really good model for languages that do have them. `obj.p = 123` as `obj.p.setValue(123)` and `delete obj.p` as `obj.p.delete()`. The type of `obj.p` is probably some sort of "dictionary key", it's delete method will have the effect of removing itself from its container.